# How to change attribute of an XML element

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I am quite new to XML. I have an XML file which contains around 8000 products and I will import these products into my own system. I want to modify this XML file for my importer. Sample product on original XML file is below;

```
  <product prodID="PD42BJ1000002020" prodName="Intermec PD42" prodBrand="INTERMEC" globProdID="PD42BJ1000002020">
    <tax>KDV18</tax>
    <pic>http://.....jpg</pic>
    <prodSpec>
      <prd spec="Connectivity Interfaces" DEGER="USB - Serial RS232 - Ethernet"/>
      <prd spec="Print Width" DEGER="104"/>
      <prd spec="Printing Method" DEGER="Direct Thermal - Thermal Transfer"/>
      <prd spec="Resolution (DPI)" DEGER="203"/>
    </prodSpec>
  </product>
```

I want to change product specs to unique elements like below;

```
  <product prodID="PD42BJ1000002020" prodName="Intermec PD42" prodBrand="INTERMEC" globProdID="PD42BJ1000002020">
    <tax>KDV18</tax>
    <pic>http://.....jpg</pic>
      <pr001>Connectivity Interfaces:USB - Serial RS232 - Ethernet</pr001>
      <pr002>Print Width:104</pr002>
      <pr003>Printing Method:Direct Thermal - Thermal Transfer</pr003>
      <pr004>Resolution (DPI):203</pr004>
  </product>
```

Is it possible to change whole XML document like that?

Comment: Can you provvide us any clue on the technologie(s) you must use or not (XSLT, pure programming language, ...) ?

Comment: Hey, thank you for answering! I am going to import XML using PHP to MySQL database. The PHP code that requires is different attribute sets like <atr></attr> instead of <attr <at1 x="" y=""/> </attr>. I am quite new to XML so I don't know about XSLT :/

Comment: I don't know PHP so I can't help you further. But there do exist some libraries to handle XML -- I believe you can find something useful here on stackoverflow : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml+php

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using Perl for this, here is a way to do it using [XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $infile= shift @ARGV;

XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => { prodSpec => \&tweak_product },
                pretty_print => 'indented',
              )
          ->parsefile( $infile);

exit;

sub tweak_product
  { my( $t, $prodspec)= @_;
    my $i=0;                                       # sub tag number 
    foreach my $prd ($prodspec->children( 'prd'))  
      { my $tag= sprintf( 'pr%03d', ++$i);
        $prd->set_tag( $tag)
            ->set_text( $prd->att( 'spec') . ':' . $prd->att( 'DEGER'))
            ->del_atts;
      }
    $prodspec->erase;
    $t->flush;
  }
```